# Check/Install .NET 4.8 while running installaware exe (Installaware Studio 18)

Tags: .net, windows-installer, installaware

- Expected Work- While running installaware exe check for .NET version if its below 4.8 install it on the target machine.

To accomplish this work I tried using file bag to bundle .NET4.8 exe file and check the version at runtime
if its less than 4.8 then install the .NET exe using (Un)Install MSI package.

Installaware Script-

~(Un)Install MSI Setup~
~{85ECC8FD-53C3-4BE1-B226-3896D7767FF2}~
~ADDLOCAL=ALL,FALSE,,TRUE,$DOTNET30_FILEBAG_X64$\RGBRAST_x64\DOTNET4.8.exe,,DOTNET30_RESULT_X64,DOTNET30_ERROR_X64,FALSE~
~mMSI.dll\mMSIExec.dll~

$DOTNET30_FILEBAG_X64 variable that holds the runtime location of file bag

Result-While runing the build it just open the file explorer window to the path where .NET exe is stored.

expected- Install the exe